# How do send information from popup to parent window after redirect?

Tags: javascript, browser, event-handling, client-side

I have the following scenario:
Inside Website a, i have an iframe from website b. on website b i need to authenticate using a oauth workflow (eg. google), therefor on website b there is an event window.open(google.com/auth...). After the authentication is successful i want to return the auth token back to website b (inside the iframe).

My problem is, that i can't use window.opener since the popup is on another domain and after the redirect the information is lost.

Another approach i'm thinking about is sending the auth token to my backend, but how can i inform website b that the authentication process was done and successful. and what would be a secure way of then reading the saved auth token form the backend (i'm thinking maybe via a session id or something?)

As far as I figured out from two days of researching this, after a redirect in a popup/new tab, there is no connection between the child (popup) and parent (website b).

Also I can't do the authentication directly inside the iframe, since google doesn't allow me to load the site there.

I know it's possible somehow, and i've seen solutions where this exact workflow is implemented, i just can't figure out how.

Any help is appreciated!

I've also tried listening to the onunload or closed event on the parent website. but this is fired as soon as the website opens.

Comment: You can transmit data between windows using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), though I'd consider passing authentication/autorization information between the windows and server only.

Comment: Thanks. If the message is transported to the server, how does the parent window then know its there? do i have do to repeated polling? or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: You didn't read the linked MDN article? Postmessaging is messaging between two windows, a server is not involved in any way.

Comment: I've read the article, my question is regarding the second part of your answer, when the data is sent to the server.

Comment: In that case data should be independent from the any other windows. It should not need polling, just pass the appropriate data from the server to website b. This provides the page b being under your control, ofcourse.

Comment: Thanks. When passing data from the server to website b (which is under my control), i would rely on something like Websockets, right? Since website b is already open.

Comment: I would simply reload page b when the data is available.